# How to check convergence for series with two indices using sympy or numpy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have series with two symbols and I need to find sum with two-point accuracy. I checked results for some parts using sympy, and I know the answer, but I have no idea how to prove it. I don't even know how to prove convergence using sympy

```
import sympy as sp

i, j = sp.symbols('i, j', integer = True)
S = sp.Sum(sp.Sum(1/(i * j)*sp.sin(sp.pi*i/2)*
           sp.sin(sp.pi*(2*j-1)/2)/sp.sinh(sp.pi*i), (i, 1,sp.oo )),(j,1,sp.oo))

S.is_convergent()
```

returns

> ```
> NotImplementedError: convergence checking for more that one symbol
> containing series is not handled
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you can evaluate a Sympy `Sum` by calling  either the method `.doit()`, which returns a closed-form expression (if Sympy is able to find one), or by calling the method `.n()`, which returns a numerical approximation of the sum (floating point number). In this case, both options do not work (I would expect at least the `.n()` to give an answer).

As a workaround, you could try to perform a simplification of the sum and then attempt to evaluate it. In particular,

```
S.factor()
```

returns

[image]

which transforms the double-index sum into the product of two single-index sums. Calling

```
S.factor().doit()
```

returns

[image]

which implies that the second sum cannot be evaluated in closed-form. However, `.n()` works now.

```
S.factor().n()
```

> `0.0599820444370520`

Comment: In that case that will work, but what if I have `sp.sinh(sp.sqrt(i+j))` instead `sp.sinh(sp.pi*i)`